# How to define the access scope of a nested function as global?

Tags: r, nested-attributes

I have an R code which looks like:

```
func1 = function(a) {

  func2 = function(a) {
    return(a+2)
  }

  func3 = function(a) {
    return(a+3)
  }
  return(a+func2(a))
}
```

Is it possible that I be able to call func2 or func3 from outside func1?
eg. How do I run:

```
x <- func2(10) #from the console?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a function closure:

```
##I've removed the brackets and return to shorten the function
func1 = function(a) {
  func2 = function(a) a+2
  func3 = function(a) a+3
  return(list(func2=func2, func3=func3))
}
```

You can use the closure to share variables:

```
func1 = function(a) {
    a = a
    func2 = function() a + 2
    func3 = function() a + 3 
    return(list(func2=func2, func3=func3))
}

f = func1(50)
f$func2()
f$func3()
```

Answer (score 0):

No You can't.

func2 is defined in the scope of func1.

But The question is really ambiguous ! Any netsed function has access to the global scope.

```
a <- 10
function <- f(x){
   g <- function(y=x) x+a
   g(x)
}
```

here function g is nested and has a free variable a. 
 the interpreter lokks in the scope of g and f and next looks for a value for a in the local frame of f(the global)

Why defining a nested function as nested if you want access to it as global?

Comment: Wouldn't it work if one created all the functions in global environment (assuming one would make all the arguments fall in line accordingly)?

Comment: fall in line accordingly? I don't understand teh english here :) . But here func2 is not defined in the global environnment.

Comment: I'm saying, wouldn't it work if one defined all the functions in global environment?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Do you have an example of a nested function defined in the global environment?

Comment: @agstudy I believe RomanLustrik means un-nest the functions func2 & func3, define them outside func1, and call func2 & func3 from within func1.